# Can we add a new column to field collection in edit form?

Tags: forms

I created a topic before with this question, but i write another to be more exact on what i want to do. I have an entity with several field collections and in this field collections, several fields (text, checkbox, entity ref...). When i open the form in **EDIT** mode, i want to add a new column to my field collection and in this column i would add a simple link to go to another page. So in my other topic we told me to use "link" module but it's not working on EDIT form but just in VIEW mode. So i searched how to add a column programmatically in drupal. I tried in my HOOK_form_alter to alter the form but i can't...

I can add a new column with jQuery i think but that won't be the best solution.

Someone got an idea ?

[image: Debug of the form : here u can see the row of my field colletion]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like hook_form_alter is the way to go.

[See this for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529636/drupal-alter-node-edit-form)

See both answers because i think that waht you want to do is just add another tab at the end of the node edit form for just a link to another page.

You can always check the [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) for more information

Comment: I want to add a new "<TD>" at the end of all my field collection.. not at the end of my form.

Comment: Did you managed to alter the node edit form? Just another element at the end of yours fieldsets

Maybe something like this

`$form['field_fieldset']['element_new_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => l('Link', 'path', array('html' => TRUE)),
);`

If you want td then maybe something like this 

`$form['field_fieldset']['element_new_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => '<td>'.l('Link', 'path', array('html' => TRUE)).'</td>',
);`

The element that you are trying to atler it is a table? a select/option element?

Comment: I put a picture of the debug, you can see how the line of my field collection is created. I think it isn't possible with php and HOOK... cause in each row i must add a new field. So i don't know :/ It works with jQuery